# "Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry" with Symfony doctrine version able

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

I occasionally get "Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry ... for key 'PRIMARY'" error when updating a table through Symfony doctrine.  The table is created with a corresponding history table.  The error is not from updating the table itself, but from inserting the record in the history table.  I am using Symfony 1.4, doctrine 1.2.  Any idea what is causing this this?  Thanks.

```
$this->computer = $computerTable->findOneByMacAddress($this->props['mac_address']);
$this->computer->ip_address = $this->ip;
$this->computer->setLastCheckinAt(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) ;
$this->computer->save();

schema.yml
Computer:
    actAs:
    Timestampable: ~
    History:
        className: %CLASS%History
        auditLog: true
        deleteVersions: false
        cascadeDelete: false
columns:
    mac_address:            { type: string(13), notnull: true, }
    last_checkin_at:        { type: string(60), }
    ip_address:             { type: string(40), fixed: false, notnull: false, }
    ...
```

Comment: Post the code generating the error and the relevant parts of your schema. Also are you trying to manually update the history table or is the exception being thrown when it tries to do it automatically?

Comment: $this->computer = $computerTable->findOneByMacaddress($this->props['mac_address']);

Comment: Eh? Update your question, and that doesnt have any saving going on so there is no way it would generate a constraint violation... You need to insert, update, or delete for that to happen...

Comment: the exception is thrown when it tries to update the history table automatically.

Comment: The original code is too long to be pasted here.  I know for sure the correct record is returned.  The error is caused by saving the record in the history table.  BTW this is in a load balanced environment.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely `findOneByMacAddress` doesn't find an existing record in some cases and you have an empty column mac address that you are saving into the database.

Try something like this:

```
if(!$this->computer = $computerTable->findOneByMacAddress($this->props['mac_address']))
{
   $this->computer = new Computer();
}
/*do logic here*/
$this->computer->save();
```

Comment: That's not the issue. If $this->computer is not empty, an exception wouldn't been thrown before the record is saved.